# How to manage memory error in python?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

This is  the code I have, to count the frequency

```
import collections
import codecs
import io
from collections import Counter
with io.open('Combine.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as infh:
    words =infh.read().split()
    with open('Counts2.txt', 'wb') as f:
        for word, count in Counter(words).most_common(100000000):
            f.write(u'{} {}\n'.format(word, count).encode('utf-8'))
```

When I try to  read a big file( 4 GB)  I am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "counter.py", line 7, in <module>
    words =infh.read().split()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 296, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
MemoryError
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.4,  8 GB RAM  Intel Core i7
How to fix this error ?
/

```
usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 296, in decode
        (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    MemoryError
```

Comment: see [this](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy)

Comment: Don't read the whole file into memory at once?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python

Comment: To read a file word by word, use a space as the delimiter with the answer to [How to read records terminated by custom separator from file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19600475/222914)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the pythonic way to process a file line-by-line:

```
with open(...) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        pass
```

This will take care of opening and closing the file, including if an exception is raised in the inner block, plus it treats the file object `fh` as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered I/O and manages memory so you don't have to worry about large files.

Comment: What if all the words are on a single line?

Comment: It should be trivial to either: a) convert it to one-word-per-line via your shell or b) read from a file in chunks (ie. manually manage memory) and process accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis errors is at usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 296, in decode
        (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    MemoryError

Answer (score -2):

How about readline instead of read()

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html