# Low-overhead method of reading from a popen handle

Tags: python, python-2.7, io, subprocess, popen

I have inherited code that enters a busy loop reading the output of a subprocess looking for a keyword, but I would like it to work with lower overhead. The code is as follows:

```
def stdout_search(self, file, keyword)
    s = ''
    while True:
        c = file.read(1)
        if not c:
            return None
        if c != '\r' and c != '\n':
            s += c
            continue
        s = s.strip()
        if keyword in s:
            break
        s = ''
    i = s.find(keyword) + len(keyword)
    return s[i:]

def scan_output(self, file, ev)
    while not ev.wait(0):
        s = self.stdout_search(file, 'Keyword:')
        if not s:
            break
        # Do something useful with s
        offset = #calculate offset
        wx.CallAfter(self.offset_label.SetLabel offset)
        #time.sleep(0.03)
```

The output from the `Popen`ed process is something like:

```
Keyword: 1 of 100
Keyword: 2 of 100
...etc...
```

Uncommenting the `time.sleep(0.03)` at the end of `scan_output` takes the load on a single core down from 100% to an acceptable 25% or so, but unfortunately the offset label redraw stutters, and although I am reading a frame count from a 30 fps playback, the label often updates less than once a second. How can I implement this code with a more correct wait for input?

BTW, the full code [may be found here](https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware/blob/master/ros/src/util/packages/runtime_manager/scripts/runtime_manager_dialog.py#L1843).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading one byte at a time is inefficient. See [Reading binary file in Python and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20014805/4279).

If you don't need an immediate feedback; [use `Popen.communicate()` to get all output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760215/4279) at once.

To avoid freezing your GUI, you could [put IO into a background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32682520/4279). It is a simple portable option for a blocking IO that supports incremental reading.

To handle the output as soon as it is flushed by the child process, you could use asynchronous I/O such as Tkinter's [`createfilehandler()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978#file-tkinter-read-async-subprocess-output-py), Gtk's [`io_add_watch()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63#file-show-subprocess-output-io-watch-py), etc -- you provide a callback and the GUI calls it when the next chunk of data is ready.

If the child flushes the data too often; the callback may just read the chunk and  put it in a buffer then you could process the buffer every X seconds using [Tkinter's `widget.after()`, Gtk's `GObject.timeout_add()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279) or whenever it reaches a certain size or certain number on lines, etc.

To read until `'Keyword:'`, you could use a code similar to [asyncio's `readuntil()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bba5177cc16d9fbd8c2a79ca82db841aa06f5455/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#L487-L574). See also, [How to read records terminated by custom separator from file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19600475/4279)