# Combining Characters using lambda in python

Tags: python, lambda

I want to result using 'str += ' style in the lambda function

example (with error) :

```
t=lambda text text : [c for c in text str += c.upper()]
t(['h','e','l','l','o'])
```

I expect to result as :

```
HELLO
```

How can i fix above lambda function with state variable like 'str +=' style

if 'str +=' style not possible, please explain in detail why the impossible. Do not just Short-Answer that wrong.

Comment: There are at least two syntax errors in the above code. Please post valid Python.

Comment: BTW, although you _can_ concatenate strings using `+=` it is better to use `.join`, please see [Why is ''.join() faster than += in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312099/why-is-join-faster-than-in-python) and the linked pages for details.

Comment: Note that assigning a `lambda` expression to a name defeats the entire purpose of `lambda` expressions and is expressly recommended against in PEP-8.

Comment: i will confirm to lambda function which possible save state like 'str +=' style

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that, but assignment statements are not possible in `lambda` functions, as they can only contain expressions, not statements. If you're assigning it to a name, you might as well use a traditional function definition.

Comment: Also, don't use `str` as a variable name (even in example code) as that shadows the built-in `str` type.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean this:

```
>>> t = lambda text: ''.join(text).upper()
>>> t(['h','e','l','l','o'])
'HELLO'
```

Documentation: [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)

Comment: Is it more efficient to do the `.upper()` after the `join`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Probably. I was just mimicking OP's style a little

Comment: 'I want to use the `str += ` style in the lambda function.'

Comment: @DanielLee That's not really an (efficient) thing

Comment: @TerryA, His question mentions it twice. I agree your way is better but at least explain that to him in your answer.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Yes, it's more efficient to call `.upper()` once on the output string than to call it for each input string.