# Why does "".join() appear to be slower than +=

Tags: python

Despite this question [Why is ''.join() faster than += in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312099/why-is-join-faster-than-in-python) and it's answers and this great explanation of the code behind the curtain: https://paolobernardi.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/python-string-concatenation-vs-list-join/
My tests suggest otherwise and I am baffled.
Am I doing something simple, incorrectly? I'll admit that I'm fudging the creation of x a bit but I don't see how that would affect the outcome.

```
import time
x="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
y=""
t1 = (time.time())
for i in range(10000):
    y+=x
t2 = (time.time())
#print (y)
print (t1,t2,"=",t2-t1)
```

(1473524757.681939, 1473524757.68521, '=', 0.0032711029052734375)

```
import time
x="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
y=""
t1 = (time.time())
for i in range(10000):
    y=y+x
t2 = (time.time())
#print (y)
print (t1,t2,"=",t2-t1)
```

(1473524814.544177, 1473524814.547544, '=', 0.0033669471740722656)

```
import time
x=10000*"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
y=""
t1 = (time.time())
y= "".join(x)
t2 = (time.time())
#print (y)
print (t1,t2,"=",t2-t1)
```

(1473524861.949515, 1473524861.978755, '=', 0.029239892959594727)

As can be seen the `"".join()` is much slower and yet we're told that it's meant to be quicker.
These values are very similar in both python2.7 and python3.4

**Edit:**
Ok fair enough.

The "one huge string" thing is the kicker.

```
import time
x=[]
for i in range(10000):
    x.append("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
y=""
t1 = (time.time())
y= "".join(x)
t2 = (time.time())
#print (y)
print (t1,t2,"=",t2-t1)
```

(1473526344.55748, 1473526344.558409, '=', 0.0009288787841796875)

An order of magnitude quicker.
Mea Culpa!

Comment: Using `time.time()` is hugely inaccurate as it is sensitive to OS interrupts and other programs running on your system. Use the `timeit` module to run multiple (thousands) of trial runs instead.

Comment: Also, you called `''.join()` on **one huge string**, not a list.

Comment: You named that tune in 2 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called `''.join()` on **one huge string**, not a list (multiplying a string produces a larger string). This forces `str.join()` to iterate over that huge string, joining 74k *individual `'x'` characters*. In other words, your second test does 74 times more work than your first.

To conduct a fair trial, you need to start with the same inputs for both, and use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to reduce the influence of garbage collection and other processes on your system.

That means both approaches need to work from a *list* of strings (your assignment examples rely on repeatedly adding a string literal, stored as a constant):

```
from timeit import timeit

testlist = ['x' * 74 for _ in range(100)]

def strjoin(testlist):
    return ''.join(testlist)

def inplace(testlist):
    result = ''
    for element in testlist:
        result += element
    return result

def concat(testlist):
    result = ''
    for element in testlist:
        result = result + element
    return result

for f in (strjoin, inplace, concat):
    timing = timeit('f(testlist)', 'from __main__ import f, testlist',
                    number=100000)
    print('{:>7}: {}'.format(f.__name__, timing))
```

On my Macbook Pro, on Python 3.5, this produces:

```
strjoin: 0.09923043003072962
inplace: 1.0032496969797648
 concat: 1.0027298880158924
```

On 2.7, I get:

```
strjoin: 0.118290185928
inplace: 0.85814499855
 concat: 0.867822885513
```

`str.join()` is still the winner here.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see the answer, I was busy sorting out the "one huge string".

Answer (score 2):

You are not comparing the same operation because your first operation added the long string every iteration while join added every item of the string seperatly. (See also @MartijnPieters answer)

If I run a comparison I get completly different timings suggesting that `str.join` is much faster:

```
x = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

def join_inplace_add(y, x, num):
    for _ in range(num):
        y += x
    return y

def join_by_join(x, num):
    return ''.join([x for _ in range(num)])

%timeit join_by_join('', x, 1000)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 91 µs per loop
%timeit join_inplace_add(x, 1000)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 325 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to point out my stupid error, I really should have known better.