# GAE Python code MUCH slower in production than locally

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine

In my Python GAE app, the following snippet of code is MUCH slower in production than when run locally.  The processing goes like this:

1. A text file of about 1 MB is loaded in a POST.  Each line of the text file is an "item".
2. My code creates a list of items from the text file and checks for duplicates and validity (by comparing against a compiled RE).

Here is the code:

```
def process_items(self, text):
    item_list = text.split()
    item_set = set()
    n_valid = 0
    n_invalid = 0
    n_dups = 0
    out = ""
    for item in item_list:
        if item in item_set:
            n_dups += 1
            out += "DUPLICATE: %s\n" % item
        elif valid_item(item): # This compares against a compiled RE
            item_set.add(item)
            n_valid += 1
            out += "%s\n" % item
        else:
            n_invalid += 1
            out += "INVALID: %s\n" % item
    return out
```

When I run this on the local dev server, a 1MB file of 50,000 lines takes 5 seconds to process.

When I run this in production, the same file takes over a minute and the request times out.  The file upload only takes about a second so I know the bottle neck is the above code.

In the past, production code was about the same speed as my local code.  I don't think this code has changed, so I suspect there may have been a change on Google's end.

Any idea why this code is now much slower in production?
Anything I can do to make this code faster?  I need to return an annotated file to the user that indicates which lines are duplicates and which lines are invalid.

EDIT:

In response to mgilson's comment, I tried the following code, and it made a huge difference in execution time!  The processing that previously timed out after a minute now takes only about 5 seconds.  GAE is still slower than expected (even accounting the relatively slow server CPUs), but with the improved algorithm, it doesn't matter for me now.

```
def process_items(self, text):
    item_list = text.split()
    item_set = set()
    n_valid = 0
    n_invalid = 0
    n_dups = 0
    for i, item in enumerate(item_list):
        item = item.strip()
        if item in item_set:
            n_dups += 1
            item_list[i] = "DUPLICATE: %s" % item
        elif valid_item(item): # This compares against a compiled RE
            item_set.add(item)
            n_valid += 1
            item_list[i] = item
        else:
            n_invalid += 1
            item_list[i] = "INVALID: %s" % item
    return "\n".join(item_list)
```

Comment: Comparing local running and running on GAE isn't really fair.  Depending on your set [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment#instance_classes), you could have a CPU limit as low as 600MHz.  Most personally computers are _significantly_ faster than that now.  One immediately obvious optimization that _might_ help is to accumulate the results in a list and `return "".join(results)` at the end rather than using `+=`.  See [Why is ''.join() faster than += in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39312099/748858) for example ...

Comment: Making `process_items` a generator `yielding` one line at a time would also speed up its overall processing time by obviating the slow `+=`

Comment: @mgilson, My Mac is 2.2 GHz so it is 3.7x faster than GAE.  For this Python code, my Mac is at least 12x faster than GAE.  That still seems like a big discrepancy though I realize that many factors make it an imperfect comparison.

Comment: Is the time taken consistent from run to run.Also is an instance running or do you have startup time in the mix. Try creating a new appengine instance and test you performance there. You may be consistently on a node that is being hammered by other services.  This is a straight out CPU task.

Comment: @TimHoffman, I do it a few times in a row on an instance used only by me so startup time is not a factor.  It has been consistent between yesterday and today and over several subsequent runs each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not at all unexpected that GAE production would run slower than locally -- Depending on your [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment#instance_classes), your production CPU can be throttled as low as 600MHz which is significantly slower than most developer computers.

One thing you *can* do to speed things up is to accumulate your results in a list (or yield them from a generator) and then use `str.join` to get the full result:

```
def process_items(self, text):
    item_list = text.split()
    item_set = set()
    n_valid = 0
    n_invalid = 0
    n_dups = 0
    out = []
    for item in item_list:
        if item in item_set:
            n_dups += 1
            out.append("DUPLICATE: %s\n" % item)
        elif valid_item(item): # This compares against a compiled RE
            item_set.add(item)
            n_valid += 1
            out.append("%s\n" % item)
        else:
            n_invalid += 1
            out.append("INVALID: %s\n" % item)
    return "".join(out)
```