# Cannot understand specific Python 3 code

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

While trying to solve a problem on Hackerank([The Problem](http://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists/problem)). I checked the solutions of people who have solved this problem. Here is the solution from one person-

```
n = input()
l = []
for _ in range(n):
    s = raw_input().split()
    cmd = s[0]
    args = s[1:]
    if cmd !="print":
        cmd += "("+ ",".join(args) +")"
        eval("l."+cmd)
    else:
        print l
```

I cannot understand line 8 and line 9, can someone explain me these lines? Can i write line 8 and line 9 in Python 3 as i'm learning Python 3 ? How ?

Comment: FYI: That code is very un-pythonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, cmd is constructed by appending the command (say "insert"), to the operands. This cmd forms a correct python expression (for example l.insert(0,5), to insert 5 at index 0, in list l).

Here, l. is hardcoded(start of line 9), cmd is initialized in cmd = s[0], and operands are added in line 8.

eval(str) evaluates the command str, in string format, as if it were in a command line.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to just include the problem :) . The input is a (text) file as below:

```
Sample Input 0

12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort
print
pop
reverse
print
```

And the expected output for a correct answer is as below:

```
Sample Output 0

[6, 5, 10]
[1, 5, 9, 10]
[9, 5, 1]
```

Before looking at the answer you quoted it would be good to read about [eval](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#eval); it takes the argument provided and tries to run it as a python expression using the global and local namespace. So in this case it needs only the local for the `"l"`-list and `"cmd"`-tuple.

What is happening is the following:

1. Empty list l is created.
2. The "command" (`cmd`) single-value list is parsed from the line by slicing (`cmd = s[0]`), since every line starts with or only has a list method
3. The other arguments are placed in `args`
4. **Line 8 (as asked):** These other arguments are then joined in a string tuple. So "insert 0 5" gives "insert" for `l` and `"(0, 5)"` for `cmd`
5. **Line 8 *continued* (as asked):** `cmd` is then combined with `args` using string concatenation (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675898/is-python-string-concatenation-bad-practice) for a good and bad example) resulting in "insert(0,5)" as value for `cmd`
6. **Line 9 (as asked):** the eval parameter is yet another string concatenation yielding "l.insert(0,5)" as final expression to be interpreted. Which then inserts integer value `5` on spot 0 in list `l` (pushing forward any other values already in `l`)

Hope it helps, keep on trucking!