# Python string.replace() not replacing certain characters

Tags: python

```
def replace_at_index(string, index):
    print (string.replace(string[index], "-", 1))
```

That's my current code for replacing a character with a given index.

- string "House" with Index 4 produces "Hous-"
- string "Housee" with Index 5 produces "Hous-e"
- string "Houseed" with Index 6 produces "Housee-"
- string "Houseed" with Index 5 produces "Hous-ed"

Not sure why it's doing this. The result I'm wanting is for it to replace the given Index, which in the case of "Housee" Index 5 would be "House-"

Comment: It's replacing the first occurrence of the character you asked it to replace. If there are duplicate characters, it won't necessarily be at the same index that you got the character from.

Comment: The usual way is `s = s[0:5] + '-' + s[6:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the function doc-string: `string.replace(old, new, count)`
so it replaces `count` as many occurences that it can find.

You cannot change a string. Each string is newly created, it is immutable. What you want is:

```
def replace_at_index(string, index):
    string = string[:index] + "-" + string[index+1:]
    return string
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a hack but works:

```
def replace_at_index(string, index):
   ls = list(string)
   ls[index] = "-"
   s = "".join(ls)
   print(s)
```

Comment: That's not a hack at all, that's a perfectly fine implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The replace method replaces a given substring in a string.

What the code is doing, it's replacing the first occurrence of the character in the string.

What you should do instead is:

```
def replace_at_index(string, index):
    new_string = string[:index]
    new_string += "-"
    new_string += string[index+1:]
    return new_string
```

In a pythonic fashion ;)

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: Yep. Long time programming in C led to this

Comment: Using `+=` on strings is actually [not super Pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39680089/4518341), but either way, it's simpler to join all at once: `new_string = string[:index] + '-' + string[index+1:]`

Comment: By pythonic i meant by using string slices. Thanks for the observation, though :)

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace` is not replacing the index, but the first occurrence of a value. Since `"Housee"[5] == 'e'`, it will replace the first `'e'`

```py
def replace_at_index(string, index):
    newstr = string[:index] + '-' + string[index+1:]
    return newstr
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's replacing the first occurrence of the character you asked it to replace. If there are duplicate characters, it won't necessarily be at the same index that you got the character from.

-- [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589489/python-string-replace-not-replacing-characters-near-end#comment117714417_66589489) by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

What you could do instead is slice the string at the index, then join it on the replacement.

```
def replace_at_index(string, index):
    parts = string[:index], string[index+1:]
    return "-".join(parts)


for s, i in ("House", 4), ("Housee", 5), ("Houseed", 6), ("Housee", 5):
    print(replace_at_index(s, i))
```

Output:

```
Hous-
House-
Housee-
House-
```

Although you might want to add a check to make sure that `index` is in range.

Answer (score 0):

its replacing you just have to be a little smart about it:

```
b = '?<\>:/"|'
line='?sqfsq?QSqdqdf/qsdfqsdf\qsdfqs"'
s=""
for char in b:
    print(char)
    # if char in b:
    s=(line.replace(char,''))
    line=s
print(line)
print(s)
```